Power Query: Error on dynamic file path for txt file
I wanted to develop dynamic file path for txt file but it keeps giving me error on the "filecontents" step below:
let  
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FolderPath"]}[Content],
    FolderPath = Source{0}[FolderPath header],
    
    Sourcev2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath_P2C"]}[Content],
    FilePath = Sourcev2{0}[FilePath_Plant to Company header],
    
    FullPath = FolderPath & FilePath,

    fileContents = File.Contents(FullPath),
    
    lines = Lines.FromBinary(fileContents, null, null, 1252),
    
    table = Table.FromColumns({lines})

in
    table

The error is

DataFormat.Error: The supplied file path must be a valid absolute path.

The file path is correct when I debugged it, Im not sure how to solve this.

Excel: Getting the Absolute Path of the current excel file
In Excel create a cell with this formula.
= TEXTBEFORE(@CELL("filename",A1),  "\[" )

That gives you the absolute path ( the folder )
If want just the filename, it's in this formula:
= TEXTBEFORE(
         TEXTAFTER(@CELL("filename",A1),  "[" ),
         "]"
    )

Power Query Full Path
What is the value of FullPath ? Something is not exact.
You might be missing the folder delimiter ? Try this
FullPath  = FolderPath & "\" & FilePath,

Another option if you know the folder, but not necessarily the filename:
= Folder.Contents( FolderPath )

You can find the newest txt in a folder.
let Source = Folder.Contents( FolderPath ),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Custom1, each ([Extension] = ".txt")),
    #"Newest txt file" = Table.First( 
        Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date modified", Order.Descending}}) )
in 
    #"Newest txt file"

You could filter the base name with  a case-insensitive Text.Contains match
